# Get Downloadable Link Hash

Tags: magento-1.8, downloadable, download-link

Magento 1.4.0.1

```
/downloadable/download/link/id/MC43OTA2MzIwMCAxNDQ3NTc2NTczMTg1MjE3MDM0MDY5MDE,/
```

I need to get the hash (`MC43OTA2MzIwMCAxNDQ3NTc2NTczMTg1MjE3MDM0MDY5MDE,`) ONLY from this:

```
$this->getPurchasedLinkUrl($link);
```

Is there a function to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash value is stored as `link_hash` column in the `downloadable_link_purchased_item` table.

It seems you're working in one of the template files so the easiest solution is to use `$link->getLinkHash()`.